# С какой стороны ковырять Exim+Dovecot+AfterLogic?

Tags: debian, vds, exim, ispmanager, dovecot

Добрый день. Пытаюсь настроить почту на VDS, там стоит ОС Debian + панель ISPManager Lite 5.67.1 + Exim 4 + Dovecot + веб-интерфейс AfterLogic. Вообще непонятно, с какой стороны к этому подступать. Требуется создать почтовый ящик с именем zakaz@domain.ru, и научиться его настраивать на почтовый клиент.

1) пытался под рутом зайти в веб-интерфейс AfterLogic - не пускает;
2) создал в ОС пользователя zakaz - ничего не изменилось.

Как настройки почты вывести в ISP Manager? В консоли не понимаю, как и что ковырять, конфиги у Exim напрочь мутные.

Answer (score 1):

В ISP Manager есть возможность управления почтовым сервисом EXIM

Но сперва необходимо в ISP Manager создать почтовый домен

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Рад был помочь)